# max-width does nothing for tables

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying a very simple thing (I thought) but it just doesn't work.
If I set a table style like that:

```css
    table {
     width: 537px;
     height: 19px;
     max-width:  100%; 
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ffe129;">text</td>
    <td style="background-color: #bdff4d;">text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then the table width will be `537px` even if my window width if 400px.
A div would be `400px`.

Adding `display:block` to the table style breaks the table: [see here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/c5ckotgy/3/)

Answer (score 3):

I will define the `max-width: 537px;` for example and then give the `width: 100%` by this way it will take the `max-width` which is **537px** if you say the `width:100%`; it will be always **respecting the width of the screen** and it will not go more than **537px**

```css
table
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 19px;
 max-width:  537px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #ffe129;"></td>
<td style="background-color: #bdff4d;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is a good solution. In case of tables `width` acts the same as `max-width`

Comment: my problem is that the width is defined inline and I can't change it.

Comment: @Entretoize you mean you can't change the width in the css because it's already defined inline? if you want your css to be stronger than your inline style use `!important` so you can do it like that `table{ width: 100% !important; height: 19px; max-width:  537px;}`

Comment: No, in fact this is in joomla, a user can create a table and set the width, which is written inline, so next If I set the width to 100% I lost the width he set so I can't overwrite. For div it works using max-width:100% but not for table.